# Understanding JSON Response with PHP json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have an HTML form that submits to a PHP file for MySQL insertion using the Jquery Form Plugin's .ajaxSubmit method. I was having trouble getting error responses from the server if there were errors, and a success response if there were no errors. I've got the code working, but I don't understand **why!**

Pertinent snippet of the PHP submission file:

```
$reqs = array('userName', 'Pwd', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'cellPhone', 'homePhone', 'role');
foreach($reqs as $req) {
    if((!isset($_POST[$req])) || (empty($_POST[$req]))) {
            $newerr = "The field " . $req . " is required.";
            $errors[] = $newerr;
    }
}
if(!empty($errors)) {
echo json_encode($errors, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
} else {
```

then create the MySQL record and

```
$success = array('response'=>"Request successfully submitted. Your account must be configured before you can access the user panel. Please watch for an email confirming your registration and configuration.");
        echo json_encode($success);
```

The success function in the .js is:

```
function processJson(data) {
    if(data.response) {
        $("#frmPrntRgstr").slideUp("normal", function() {
            $("#frmPrntRgstrRspns").append(data.response).slideDown("normal");
        })
    } else {
        for(var error in data) {
        $("#frmPrntRgstr").prepend(data[error]);
        }
    }
}
```

This does what I want it to, and I understand the first part. There is only a `'response'` key in the JSON object if it's gotten past error checking. Firebug shows this as the server Response:

```
{"response":"Request successfully submitted. Your account must be configured before you can access the user panel. Please watch for an email confirming your registration and configuration."}
```

I don't understand why the syntax `'data[error]'` or simply `'data'` works for reading back the errors. The response shown in Firebug is:

```
{"0":"The field cellPhone is required.","1":"The field homePhone is required."}
```

The JSON shown in Firebug is:

```
0        "The field cellPhone is required."

1        "The field homePhone is required."
```

It doesn't say error in the key, and it doesn't define a new "Errors" object. So why does that Javascript allow the definition `'data[error]'` if there's neither an object nor a key defined as error in the response? I guess `'data'` works because it's just reading back each value in the returned object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON encodes the contents of a variable, but does not include the variable's own name. Nothing says that you have to pass back only a single string via JSON. You can encode an entire message system in a single variable. So encode any messages you want, a sub-variable to say "error occured", any error message(s) associated with that error condition, etc...

```
$msgs = array();
if (...) {
    $msgs['message'] = 'blah blah blah';
}

if (...) {
    $msgs['errors'][] = 'error message here';
}

echo json_encode($msgs);
```

Then you can have your JS check for any errors with `if (data.errors.length > 0)` or similar.

Comment: To use the second example, would I have to `echo json_encode($msgs, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`? Because `echo json_encode($msgs);` returns `{"errors":["error message here","another"]}`, and I thought the stuff you want to use in responses needed to be in curly braces with individual keys?

Comment: no, `[]` is an array, so it'd be `somevar.errors[0]`, `somevar.errors[1]`, etc...

Comment: So `for(var error in somevar.errors) {
   $("#frmPrntRgstr").prepend(somevar.errors[error]);
   }` would loop through all of the error messages in `somevar` prepending them to `"#frmPrntRgstr"`. The `[error]` isn't directly referring to a key or a value, it's just a placeholder for the values of all the "key":"value" pairs in the array `somevar.errors`?

Comment: JSON is just a string representation of a javascript data structure. Once you decode the json, it produces a javascript var no different from any other var. There'll be no difference between a var you specified manually and one that was created from a json decoder.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var error in data)
```

this is a method to walk through objects, 'error' in that case is not a label, you may see 'error' here as a variable containing the label(the current key, or better called as member-name). You may use here whatever you want to as "variable"-name.

```
for(var foo in data) {
        $("#frmPrntRgstr").prepend(data[foo]);
        }
```

...will do the same.

This is nearly similar to this PHP-code:

```
foreach($data as $error => $message )
{
    echo $data[$error]
}
```

Where $data is an array and $error the current key while walking through the array.

Comment: So in your example `var foo` is not named anywhere in the object, it's what you're calling the values object while you're using it? And the keys here would be anonymous `{"0" : "messageA", "1" : "messageB" }` and irrelevant?

Comment: foo (or error) are defined inside the loop, they will have the values 0 , 1 and so on, depending on the keys(member-names). Just put a `alert(error);` inside the loop, and you will see.